# Power measuring device for 400 amp service to determine peak usage

Tags: electrical, power-monitoring

I am trying to figure out peak usage for a building with ~60 units.  The main service is 400 amps and then splits off to individual meters.  The utility can only give me one of the meters usage.  I'd like to put some heat pump hot water tanks on the building panel to replace a natural gas hot water tank.  My calculations show I'd need ~6 heat pump hot water tanks.

The building has a 150 amp panel but the electricians concern is that we might exceed the 400 amp draw at peak usage.  This would blow the fuse for the main disconnect and all units would loose power until a replacement fuse could be installed.

If I could install a power monitoring device on the 3-phase line before it splits to the individual meters and record peak load every 5 minutes then I'd have pretty good confidence numbers to know how many I could have installed without changing out the service.

Is there anything out there that could do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not really a Home Improvement question, is it?

Inductance-style current probe clamped around each of the hots, each feeding into a recording ammeter (or both feeding a two-channel instrument), would do the job. For obvious reasons, you would want a recording ammeter that can be stuck in a corner inside the panel box, so the box can be closed up again and safely left unattended. Otherwise your electrician is going to have to baby-sit the box for the duration of the testing period. (Or it'd have to be designed with the measurements running out of the box through a knock-out or something like that.)

I believe this can be gotten off-the-shelf; I know there are semi-consumer versions that are designed for smart-home power usage monitoring but I don't know whether they're spec'd for the current range you're interested in.

This may not be cheap, but it should be easy for your electrician to set up. And if you're talking about a 60-unit building, you can afford to buy or rent proper tools.

I'm sorta surprised your electrician didn't recommend exactly this. It ain't rocket science.

Comment: "Not really a Home Improvement question, is it?" then please don't answer it... ;)

Comment: My electrician does mostly residential.  He can do commercial.  I had three electricians out.  They were hoping the utility could provide the data but they don't have it.  I didn't specifically ask the ele if he knew of a device.  I'll see if he does.

Comment: It's on the edge. The general approach given in my answer would also work if a homeowner had to measure dynamic load... though even with ever-more-efficient devices, the basic answer to "Should I upgrade from 100A to 200A service" is "If you're asking, probably yes."

Comment: I ended up finding one - iotawatt - it does 3 phase and is an open source hardware platform.  It was quite affordable in comparison to the other commercial ones I was able to find on a search.